# It says to me: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.ts(2322), however, I return the correct type

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

```
type Answer = { error: false; status: boolean } | { error: true; description: string };

   async has_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGEv1(): Promise<Answer> {
     return await this.androidPermissions
      .checkPermission(this.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
      //.then((current) => ({ error: false, status: current.hasPermission})) <--ERROR
      //.then((current) => ({ error: false as const, status: current.hasPermission})) <--NO ERROR
      .catch((error) => ({ error: true, description: error.message as string}));
   }
```

***ERROR***

```
Type '{ error: boolean; status: boolean; } | { error: true; description: string; }' 
is not assignable to type 'Answer'.
Type '{ error: boolean; status: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Answer'.
Type '{ error: boolean; status: boolean; }' is not assignable to type '{ error: false; status: boolean; }'.
Types of property 'error' are incompatible.
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'.ts(2322)
```

p.s.: if I return it as 'as const' I don't get any error, however, when I use the function it does not detect the status property.

***2nd ERROR***

```
Property 'status' does not exist on type 'Answer'.
Property 'status' does not exist on type '{ error: true; description: string; }'
```

***First Edit***

```
async has_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGEv1(): Promise<Answer> {
  return await this.androidPermissions
    .checkPermission(this.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    .then((current) => ({ error: false, status: current.hasPermission} as Answer))
    .catch((error) => ({ error: true, description: error.message as string} as Answer));
}
```

p.s.: when I use the function, it keeps telling me that the status property does not exist.

***2nd Edit***

```
await this.has_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGEv1().then(answer => {
  if (!answer.error) {
    console.log(answer.status); // <--Error
    // when I use the function, it keeps telling me that the status property does not exist.
  } else {
    console.log(answer.description);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code where the second error happens?

Comment: @TobiasS. it happens when I return error: false as const, it is in the part where it says, no error

Comment: in the 2nd then

Comment: if you assert the type of the return in the then callback to be `as Answer`, does it work then? You should probably typeguard the return since you are catching the error. so when you call the function, check on the error property. if the error is false, you will have access to status.

Comment: like this? .then((current) => ({ error: false as Answer, status: current.hasPermission})), or when I call my function?

Comment: await this.has_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGEv1().then(answer as Answer =>{})

Comment: `then((current => ({....} as Answer))`. and when calling the function: `const answer = await ....; if (!answer.error) ...` answer.status should exist inside the if block.

Comment: @Dean it keeps telling me that the status property does not exist

Comment: may you extend your original question to show where and how you are trying to access the status property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246352/discussion-between-dean-and-raulabad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!answer.error` seems to be too vague for the compiler to infer the type.

`answer.error === false` works as you expect.

```js
await this.has_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGEv1().then(answer => {
  if (answer.error === false) {
    console.log(answer.status);
  } else {
    console.log(answer.description);
  }
});
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yatio3?file=index.ts

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, why does that happen, if I apply it in another compiler that doesn't happen to me.